# Multiple comparison between two dataframes without using "for"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, comparison

I have two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`), with `guest_id`, `money`, and `date` as a result

I want to identify if an element in the first dataframe is also in the second dataframe by using these 3. For that I wish to use a variable that I would add in `df1` and that I would name `match`, which takes 1 if an element in `df1` is also in `df2`, and 0 otherwise

However they do not match perfectly (because of some errors in the report), so I can't simply merge them by these 3 columns or something like that

Therefore, I want to make some simple comparisons knowing that :

- There's no errors with the guest_id comparison so I want to check when the `guest_id` for `df1` match with `guest_id` for `df2`
- Warning : A guest_id can appear multiple times in the dataframe
- When a guest is in `df1` and in `df2`, I want to then check the `money` and `date`. I want to do it like this :

  - For `money` make the difference between the `money` in `df1` for a given `guest_id` with all the `money` that can appear in `df2` (but again only for a given `guest_id`). If there's an occurence that is close to 0 (between -1 and 1, or `<=` 1 if I use `abs()`), then I consider that the `money` match
  - For `date` : I do the same thing than in `money` ; I consider that if the `date` in `df1` is between `df2$date - 5` ; `df2$date + 5` , then the `date` match (again, I want to do these comparisons only for a given `guest_id`, without looking at the whole dataframe, otherwise it might match `money` or `date`, but for another guest, and that's what I have trouble dealing with)
- Hence, if I have a match for `guest_id`, the `money`, and the `date`, I can put 1 in my `match` variable, otherwise it's a 0

I used `dplyr`, but as I'm a beginner I have trouble finding the right sequence of functions to use. I'd also rather avoid using `for` since I'm working with big dataframes so it would definitely take too much time to get my result

To sum it up, here's what I have :

```
df1
  guest_id  money       date
      1     10.2    2017-01-01
      1     10.3    2000-01-01
      1     50.0    2017-01-01
      2     10.5    2017-01-01
      2      9.5    2017-01-01
      3    100.0    2000-01-01

df2
  guest_id  money       date
      1     10     2017-01-01
      1     10     2015-01-01
      2     10     2017-01-03
```

And as a result :

```
df_res
  guest_id   money   date         match
       1     10.2    2017-01-01     1   #difference with money is ok to still have a match   
       1     10.3    2000-01-01     0   #match with money but not date
       1     50.0    2017-01-01     0   #match with date but not money
       2     10.5    2017-01-01     1   #match with money ; difference with date is close enough to have a match
       2      9.5    2017-01-01     1   #Also a match
       3     100.0   2000-01-01     0   #Doesn't match with guest_id
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this (or even a completely different approach of this problem) ?

Comment: Take a look at the `fuzzyjoin` package, though I am sure the use of two merging columns (where one is fuzzy and one is not) is possible.

Comment: Thanks ! At first sight it definitely seems like it could help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent versions of `data.table` support *non-equi* joins which are very handy and efficient, especially in combination with *update on join* and group by `.EACHI`:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# tolerances
tol_m <- 1
tol_d <- 5

data.table(df1)[
  # join with modified df2
  data.table(df2)[
    # create helper columns for non-equi joins
    , `:=`(m1 = money - tol_m, m2 = money + tol_m, 
           d1 = date - tol_d, d2 = date + tol_d)]
  # non-equi join
  , on = c("guest_id", "money>=m1", "money<=m2", "date>=d1", "date<=d2"), 
  # aggregate group-wise, grouped by join conditions, prettify result
  match := .N, by = .EACHI][, match := as.integer(!is.na(match))][]
```

> ```
>    guest_id money       date match
> 1:        1  10.2 2017-01-01     1
> 2:        1  10.3 2000-01-01     0
> 3:        1  50.0 2017-01-01     0
> 4:        2  10.5 2017-01-01     1
> 5:        2   9.5 2017-01-01     1
> 6:        3 100.0 2000-01-01     0
> ```

Without *non-equi joins*, we would have had to create the cartesian product of all possible combinations and eliminate those rows which don't match the conditions.

Comment: Indeed I tried and it's clearly a lot faster than doing Andrey's method (although both works very well). Thanks a lot !

Comment: If `df1` or `df2` are large objects, you can safe memory and time if you use `setDT()` instead of `data.table()`. The latter takes a copy leaving the original data.frames unchanged while `setDT()` coerces _in place_, i.e., without copying which is faster but changes `df1` and `df2`.

Answer (score 2):

I propose doing left join first, then applying your conditions and finding if any of the original rows from df1 had a match:

```
library('stringr')
library('dplyr')

df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = 'guest_id') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains('date')), ymd) %>%
  # Checking for your condition
  mutate(match = (abs(money.x - money.y) < 1) & (abs(date.x - date.y) < 5)) %>%
  # Cleaning data.frame a bit
  select(-money.y, -date.y) %>%
  setNames(str_replace(names(.), '\\.x', '')) %>%
  # Finding if rows had a match
  group_by(guest_id, money, date) %>%
  summarise(match = any(match, na.rm = TRUE))

df3
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 4
> # Groups:   guest_id, money [?]
>   guest_id money       date match
>      <int> <dbl>     <date> <lgl>
> 1        1  10.2 2017-01-01  TRUE
> 2        1  10.3 2000-01-01 FALSE
> 3        1  50.0 2017-01-01 FALSE
> 4        2   9.5 2017-01-01  TRUE
> 5        2  10.5 2017-01-01  TRUE
> 6        3 100.0 2000-01-01 FALSE
> ```

`data.frame`'s i've used for testing:

```
df1 <- structure(list(guest_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), money = c(10.2, 
10.3, 50, 10.5, 9.5, 100), date = c("2017-01-01", "2000-01-01", 
"2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2000-01-01")), .Names = c("guest_id", 
"money", "date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

df2 <- structure(list(guest_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L), money = c(10L, 10L, 
10L), date = c("2017-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2017-01-03")), .Names = c("guest_id", 
"money", "date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```